# How to render a video using GPU instead of CPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video, gpu

I am trying to render a video I edited in Blender. When I press Render Animation I expect it to use the GPU, but my GPU is sitting without changes at 9 watts, while my CPU usage jumps from 7 to 50 watts. (Task Manager does not show the correct percentage for GPU so I looked at the power values instead)

What I tried:

Set the Cycles Render Devices to my GPU:

[image: cyclerenderdevices]

And I set the Device to GPU compute in the Render Properties tab:

[image]

None of these helped. Using Windows 10 and Blender LTS 2.93, GPU is GTX 1660 SUPER.

Drivers are up to date, the GPU is working without issues in Unreal and in games.

Any ideas on how to fix this and what could be wrong?

Comment: GPU acceleration is only available for rendering 3D scenes using Cycles render engine

Comment: Is there no way to use the GPU to render videos? I thought it should work, since I am using the GPU to encode the video when recording it. Or it is just Blender not supporting this feature?

Comment: Blender doesn't have any gpu accelerated video handling features as far as I know

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying this. I am new to Blender, so I had no idea.